# duplicate post issue on pages

Tags: php, post, graph, facebook-graph-api

i've this problem since last month

let me show what's happens on my implementation of graph api using PHP:

skippin' on standard php graph api workflow to retrive basic user info such as
user access token, page access token and required permission, when i'm calling the

(example)

`$facebook->api(PAGE_ID/feed,post, access_token, message, link)`

i've got 2 posts on target page wall.

First one is a complete post with link and message objects,second one, created 3-4 seconds after the first one, only with message object.

The strange thing is that the Graph api return to my framework  the message id of the second one post only.

Since yesterday i'm getting always an Facebook exception like #506 duplicate post message.

I did see on Facebook issue tracker that a similar issue was reported las year and i'm getting serious problem with my customers if i do not find a valid solution to prevent:

1. double post
2. post without all object in the api call such as
   picture, link, name, caption
3. incorrect id

Anyone has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to prevent these dupe posts, when Facebook prevent them. Just "ignore" that error.
To prevent incorrect id => if this really happens, it's problem on their side and you should post a bug tracker

Answer (score 0):

About incorrect ID, I've noticed that the Graph API's returns a different ID from that used to get access to the post by browser. I try to discovering what's going on before report a problem. Did someone else note?

I've got this dupes too, but I don't have a clue about what could be.